# what should my php return in this case

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to submit a form without refreshing the page, and I have this form:

```
<form method="post" action="user-add.php" id="user-add-form">
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="15">
<button type="submit" name="add_user" class="btn btn-primary" id="user-add-submit">Add user</button>
</form>
```

and this jquery function ( using jquery validation plugin ):

```
submitHandler: function() {

    $('#user-add-submit').button('loading');

    var post = $('#user-add-form').serialize();
    var action = $('#user-add-form').attr('action');

    $("#message").slideUp(350, function () {

        $('#message').hide();

        $.post(action, post, function (data) {

            $('#message').html(data);
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');

            if (data.match('success') !== null) {
                $('#user-add-form input').val('');
                $('#user-add-submit').button('reset');
            } else {
                $('#user-add-submit').button('reset');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

But my question is what user-add.php should look like for the script to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You callback function answers this question itself:

```
function (data) {
    $('#message').html(data);  // #1
    $('#message').slideDown('slow');

    if (data.match('success') !== null) {  // #2
        $('#user-add-form input').val('');
        $('#user-add-submit').button('reset');
    } else {
        $('#user-add-submit').button('reset');
    }
}
```

- It has to return HTML, because the result goes directly into the DOM (#1)
- The HTML has to contain (or not contain) the case-sensitive substring "success" depending on how the operation concluded (#2)

The above holds if we assume that the function will not be modified. But it would be a good idea to modify the function to make it more computer-friendly. You could instead return some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    html: "the HTML for your page goes here",
    successful: true
}
```

Here `html` is what you want to show and `successful` is for internal consumption. This way you don't have to couple the string `"success"` with determining if the operation was successful indeed. With this scheme your callback would look like this:

```
function (json) {
    $('#message').html(json.html);  // #1
    $('#message').slideDown('slow');

    if (json.successful) {
        $('#user-add-form input').val('');
        $('#user-add-submit').button('reset');
    } else {
        $('#user-add-submit').button('reset');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to return a JSON object containing a boolean for the success flag and a string for the HTML:

```
echo json_encode(array('success' => $success, 'html' => $html));
```

Then you can change your successs callback like this - getting rid of the plain string comparison to determine if the action was successful or not is a good thing and might even be important depending on what the HTML contains (what if "success" appears somewhere else):

```
function(data) {
    $('#message').html(data.html);
    $('#message').slideDown('slow');

    if(data.success) {
        $('#user-add-form input').val('');
        $('#user-add-submit').button('reset');
    }
    else {
        $('#user-add-submit').button('reset');
    }
}
```